# List of numbers without common factors with a certain number

Tags: list-manipulation

Is there any function in Mathematica which directly gives an array of integer numbers with no common factor with a certain integer number?

For example, all the integer numbers between 0 and 1728, which do not have any common factor with 12 (apart from the common factor one ofcourse.)

I know how to make a program to do that, I just wonder wether there is a comand to do it.

Comment: why don't you show us your program...

Comment: `Select[Range[0, 1728], CoprimeQ[#, 12] &]`

Comment: @J.M.  thnks thanks!

Comment: @J.M. I think you want that predicate to be GCD[#, 12] == 1 &

Comment: @J.M. Was your comment previous to my answer? If it was, please accept my apologies.

Comment: @bel, whether it was or not, I do not mind at all; I upvoted your fine answer after all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Select[Range[0, 1728], CoprimeQ[12, #] &]
```

Comment: Why not pump it up using its listability, `Pick[#, CoprimeQ[#, 12]] &@Range[0, 1728]`

Comment: Nheee, it only seems barely faster

Comment: @Rojo The timing was worst here

Answer (score 6):

Here are a couple of ways. One is cribbed from J.M. To indicate speed I show for the range (0...10^6).

I'll view this part as preprocessing.

```
n = 10^6;
div = 12;
fax = FactorInteger[div][[All, 1]];
sqfreeprod = Times @@ fax

Timing[r1 = Select[Range[0, n], GCD[#, sqfreeprod] == 1 &];]

(* Out[562]= {1.230000, Null} *)

Timing[
 avoid = Map[Range[0, n, #] &, fax];
 r2 = Complement[Range[0, n], Sequence @@ avoid];]

(* Out[563]= {0.040000, Null} *)

r1 === r2

(* Out[564]= True *)
```

If using numbers with many factors for `div` then the gcd-based approach might be faster.

Comment: +1 This is an adaptation of the sieve of Eratosthenes. There is a time-space tradeoff: as the number of prime divisors of `div` grows, the sieve becomes less competitive.